# UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode bytes for Chinese

Tags: python, unicode, decode, splitter

Environment:
- Mac OS Yosemite
- Python 2.7
- The file file that I am reading is saved in txt format

So I have a script to segment Chinese text into sentences and below is the code:

```
# coding: utf-8 

cutlist ="。！？".decode('utf-8')    
def FindToken(cutlist, char):
    if char in cutlist:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def Cut(cutlist,lines):          
    l = []         
    line = []   

    for i in lines:         
        if FindToken(cutlist,i):      
            line.append(i)         
            l.append(''.join(line))   
            line = []  =
        else:         
            line.append(i)     
    return l


for lines in file("t.txt"):    
    l = Cut(list(cutlist),list(lines.decode('gbk')))     
    for line in l:  
       if line.strip() !="":      
            li = line.strip().split()   
            for sentence in li:
                print sentence
```

But I am getting the following error:
[image]

Can someone give me some guidance as of what is causing this error? Thanks!

Comment: Your code looks correct. The error message basically says that it cannot decode the file. So it appears the file "t.txt" may not be encoded in gbk. Can you open the file with a text editor?

Comment: Yeah I am actually able to. I also tried to include a line of chinese in the file and called it directly in the script instead of a separate file and it is still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

So I changed decode to utf-8 as following:

```
l = Cut(list(cutlist),list(lines.decode('utf-8')))
```

And it works now.